# Hide a UITableView by setting row height to 0?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

I just inherited code which hides/shows rows a UITableView by using the delegate `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method and returning height 0 for "hidden rows".

The code works, but it has me concerned there might be fraught with unforeseen complications. Can someone either ease my concerns or give me good reasons why this could cause problems (I couldn't find any issues with initial testing).

The table is fairly small <10 rows total and would require custom row heights even without this hidden row solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be cleaner to add and remove the rows between two `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` calls, but I don't see why this 0-height method should not work.

If there are no UI-artifacts, that is (e.g. the **Delete** button showing up overflowing to the next cell).

Comment: No one speaking violently against this... so I won't worry as much. Animation and such isn't really a significant issue because these changes only help when the view is off screen. Under most circumstances I would agree it's better to update the backing data model, but I'd prefer not to modify functional code without good reason.

Answer (score 3):

I do the same thing in the code I just worked on. I am not happy with different behaviour for different table view settings.
The alternative in my case is more complex (a model that adapts to what is visible or not).
For now, I put a //HACK comment on it and document a few peculiarities.
This is what I have found (iOS 5.0 tested):

1. Set tableView.rowHeight = 1; Zero will give a cell with zero height (as returned by tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:) some default height.
2. You must have a cell separator. If none is selected, then a default height is assigned to zero height rows. The height of 1 is included with the separator.

If your code works in a different way, it would be interesting to know how it is set up.

Comment: This inherited code (I didn't write it) leaves the tableview.rowheight at the default 44. In `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` it either returns 0 or tableview.rowheight depending the "shouldBeVisible" flag in the data model. The UITableViewCell object must "Clip Subviews" otherwise the internal data flows off the bottom of the hidden cell.

Answer (score 0):

I use this method of setting hidden cell heights to 0. It works well and also means I can animate the inclusion of new cells by expanding the cell height (such as adding a DatePicker Cell like the calendar app does).

A few things I have had to watch out for in iOS 7.1 are that very squashed text does still appear even when a cell height is = 0 so I've needed to remove cell text in that case. Also, I have change the size of the cell's separatorInset as that was appearing as well.

Comment: What do you mean with "removing cell text"?

Comment: I mean that if the cell contains any form of content such as text, I had to remove it or else it would still display despite the cell height being 0.

I have not tested this since that time so it may be different in iOS 8 (it certainly wasn't an issue in iOS 7.0.x and only became an issue in 7.1.x)